# Padding top and full height of display window with boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a semi-transparent navbar and a background-image and both together should be the height of the browser window.

I have a body padding-top to not have to define a container all the time. 
The problem is that navbar + background-image are now bigger than the browser window and I have a scroll bar.

[image]

How could I get rid off the scroll bar ie. navbar + background-image = browser window height without having a part of the background image behind the navbar.

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/225/

And the corresponding code:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  opacity:0.7;
  border: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; 
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;  
}

#picture{ 
    height: 100vh; 
    background-image: url("http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/06_Place_20773_1_Mis.jpg"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: bottom center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">         
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8" id="picture">
</div> 


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is body{
    "overflow:hidden;" }
helpfull ?

Comment: @Webbie, yes, I hadn't thought about this but it looks like it is the most easy and workfull solution. Maybe you should edit it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the calc css function:

```
#picture{ 
    height: calc(100vh - 50px); 
    background-image: url("http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/06_Place_20773_1_Mis.jpg"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: bottom center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the picture is 100% of the ViewHeight - after the nav-bar is drawn; so: the "scroll-height" is the height of the nav-bar.

To over-come this issue, try styling the height (% or vh) of those two elements so that together they do not exceed 100, like this:

```
.navbar
{
    /* other properties here */
    height: 15%;
}

#picture
{
    /* other properties here */
    height: 85%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
body { 
overflow: hidden;
}
```

It may helpful.

Comment: After checking on multiple screen sizes, there is a problem with this solution for intermediate and small screens: the right column disapears.